# Unirationality of moduli of curves in char $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k=\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$ and let $M_{g}$ be the moduli space of genus $g$ curves over $k$. For $g$ sufficiently large, is it known if $M_g$ is unirational or not?

(For $g>>0$, $M_g$ is of general type, therefore cannot be separably unirational. Also Mumford showed in "Abelian quotients of the Teichmüller modular group" that $\mathrm{Alb}(M)$ is trivial over $\mathbb{C}$, there seems no obvious obstructions to inseparable unirationality?)

Comment: Inseparably unirational projective varieties still have finite fundamental group (whose $p$-power part is trivial), and the prime-to-$p$ cohomology has coniveau at least one. Some compactified moduli spaces have cohomology that is not purely Tate, e.g. moduli of genus one curves with eleven marked points.  This might give a way to prove (not necessarily separable) non-unirationality.

Comment: After a quick literature search, it appears that the cohomology of $\overline{M}_g$ is of coniveau no greater than seven for $g$ large.  I do not know whether it is of coniveau strictly less than one (which would settle not-necessarily-separable unirationality).

Comment: Thanks! Do we know if $M_g$ always have a Zariski dense set of rational curves?

Comment: We do not even know the answer to that in characteristic zero.  The Lang-Vojta Conjecture predicts a negative answer in characteristic zero, cf. work of Caporaso-Harris-Mazur.  However, that conjecture is wide open.